# Why is my text changing size randomly

Tags: php, javascript, css, xhtml

A little disclaimer before I get ridiculed for not putting up code examples: I would have to put my whole site on here so there is nothing really specific except a combination of PHP,CSS,JAVESCRIPT,and XHTML that creates 70 plus pages

Basically I am just looking for a guess on what it could be making my text change sizes randomly. I can reload the same page and it could be the same or change

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: When you say text sizes, do you mean the font size or the length of the text?

Comment: What is changing the text size? This should be relatively easy to discover with firebug or any other css debugging tool to see what the contributing factors might be. While I understand that your code stack might be enormous, we need a lot more information to diagnose this problem.

Comment: The disclaimer here is really not a good excuse.  Use your browser's "File -> Save Page As -> Web Page, complete", then load the saved page to see if the problem still happens. Then start deleting stuff from the saved file.

Comment: One common occurence is that you might have a tag that wasn't closed and that could be effecting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No guessing necessary. Install [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843), right click the text, click "inspect element" and find out exactly why. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you atleast have a URL that you can point to so we can see it for ourselves?! Without some point of reference the only feasible that could be given is "because you're doing it wrong".

Comment: Well by the looks of all the helpful responses I have received, "because your doing it wrong" is not the only feasible answer.

Comment: Ralph The Mouf, So far you have only received one possible solution which was given by Jason Orendorff. Dustin's response could have been written as "because you didn't provide examples we have to assume you did something wrong". And the accepted "answer" isn't a solution but rather a way for you to debug your own site. I completely agree that you should use firebug to help resolve your problem.

Comment: martinatime is correct in that I could have phrased that more clearly. You are *incorrect* in that the only feasible answer you received was akin to "you're doing it wrong, here's how you fix it yourself, as you seem unwilling to provide us the minimum prerequisite to assist you any further". 

I am, however, glad that Pekka was able to provide you an answer that allowed you to resolve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a stylesheet that affects the font size sometimes loads and sometimes fails to load.

(Stylesheets are usually static and therefore can be cached, so this would be a symptom of an underlying problem with your site.)